# How does the "composer" package manager work?

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I am trying to install "[Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/)"

It says there are two ways to install, I tried the first one (download the PHP file and include it into my project) and it worked fine.

Now I am trying the second way (using composer).

[image]

Bunch of questions emerge at the second I see it.

- Where to run this command?
- Is it equivalent to downloading the "class.krumo.php"  file and other skin files to the current folder?
- Do I still need to include the file in my PHP?
- Or, maybe through running this command, krumo becomes a built-in function of PHP on my machine (so I can use it "out-of-box" on any PHP file)?

I managed to find that this `install` command doesn't actually work (probably outdated), and found out that I had to run `composer require kktsvetkov/krumo`. I did so and got this:

> [image: composer output]

It seems to me it is finally installed. Under the folder there are only two files added "composer.lock" and "composer.json", the class.krumo.php file is nowhere to be found, and of course calling `krumo()` in a test PHP file throws the error `call to undefined function krumo`.

I need a big picture of how composer packages work.

Comment: The krumo files should be inside the `vendor` folder of your project, that's where composer puts the packages you downloaded. As for using krumo, you must first include the [`autoload.php`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) of composer. Then it is the matter of checking the documentation of krumo on how to call it

Comment: More info about Composer usage [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Comment: `require('vendor/autoload.php);` but also read the docs Carl linked.

Comment: Sorry, for that bumpy first go at composer. That is really unfortunate. I don't think there are any good beginners guides for it. The docs are a start, but probably require quite a bit of prior knowledge to be truly helpful. I have bookmarked your question and when I have some more time I hope to come back to it with a quick 101 to get you or anyone else new to composer up to speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand what composer is. It's a "dependency manager". So it *manages your application dependencies*, basically the libraries your application needs to work.

It does so recursively. So if your application requires `NiceDependency` to work, and `NiceDependency` in turn requires `AnotherNicePackage`, it installs both. It deals also with conflict resolution (when one of your dependencies requires something that's not compatible with something that *another* of your dependencies require).

The file where your dependencies are declared is [`composer.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md).

So when you run `composer require [some-vendor/some-package]`, a few things happen behind the curtain. Simplifying things a lot:

- If your `composer.json` file doesn't exist, it will create it.
- It will try to find your dependency in the central repository ([packagist.org](https://packagist.org/))
- If found, it will download the package and store it in the `vendor` directory.
- It will update your `composer.json` it to add your dependency to the `require` key.

In the process, it will resolve all the nested dependencies and do the same for those.

When it's done, it will also create a `composer.lock` file.

This "lock" file stores a frozen snapshot of all the references to all the packages that were actually installed. This is necessary because when you declare your dependencies  you can define a range of versions (e.g "anything greater or equal than version 2.2; but lower than version 2.3"). Your `composer.lock` would store the specific version that's actuall installed (e.g. "version 2.2.4").

Later, if someone got your project files and executed `composer install`, the *lock* file would be read so they installed exactly the same files as you did.

(`require` adds a dependency to your project's composer.json file; `install` reads your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files and sets up a project from there; there is also a `update` command that would read only `composer.json`, download the latest available packages respecting to the version restrictions in each dependency, and update `composer.lock accordingly)

Additionally, composer helps with [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), to make the process of actually using the installed libraries easier and faster for developers.

Autoloading is **very** convenient. Not only you no longer have to add a `require someclass.php;` statement for each class you want to use, but you also gain the advantage of not having to read these files *until they are actually needed*.

So not only it simplifies using these new classes, it helps making your application perform better.

For this, inside the `vendor` directory a file named `autoload.php` is created. Typically, you need to `require` this file as the first thing you do on your application entry point.

For example, assuming you have a structure like this:

```
- project root/
--- composer.json
--- composer.lock
--- vendor/
--- public/
----- index.php
```

Your `index.php` file should read:

```php
// public/index.php
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

This would allow you to use any installed library normally. In the case of the tool you want to install:

```php
// public/index.php
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$a = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => [1, 2, 3],
    'xxx' = false
];

krumo($a);
```

<sub>As a side note, that library seems to be quite old. I'd try to get something a bit newer. I'd recommend [Symfony's VarDump component.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html)</sub>

<sub>And no, it is not a particularly friendly "newbie" tool. It helps dealing with a lot of things, but it's mostly aimed to slightly more advanced users, since it helps solving issues that aren't so significant in starter/very simple projects.</sub>